# Does webdriverio support folder upload?

Tags: automated-tests, webdriver-io

I am trying to upload a folder. I am using the below code from wdio official documentation.

```
const path = require('path');
const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'path/to/your/file');
const remoteFilePath = browser.uploadFile(filePath);
$('.upload-data-file-input').setValue(remoteFilePath);
```

If I remove the third line, it works fine.

Comment: Removing the third line would lead to an error for undefined `remoteFilePath` variable. I presume you're sending the hardcoded path via `.setValue(<youPath>)`. In which case, Yes, it is known that you can pass the file-path like that and the file is uploaded. Not all sites support this approach though. 

Does this answer your question?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. But it does not solve my problem.

This approach wont work when you run the code on a remote machine because the file does not exist on the remote machine where the browser is running.

WebdriverIO has implemented the upload command to tackle this scenario. My problem is that this approach is not working while uploading folders. It is working fine when I try to upload a file.

Comment: Well, you have to have the file available on the remote machine, as in your local scenario. That goes without saying. This is not a framework limitation, but a scenario reality. Add the mock file in your assets folder, or store it before-hand via fs in a `before` hook. Good luck!